# If $1<a$ how would I prove $n(a^{n}-1)-1$ is positive for any positive integer n? Is it possible to prove with the information given?

Tags: inequality

I've deduced:

$a^{n}>1 \Rightarrow a^{n}-1>0 \Rightarrow n(a^{n}-1)>0 \Rightarrow n(a^{n}-1)>-1$.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Consider $a=3/2$ and $n=1$ for a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you @dxiv. This was something that needed to hold true for a proof I am currently doing, so that rules out this approach.

Comment: If $n(a^{n}-1)-1>0$ for all $n$ then for $n=1$ we get $a > 2$ as in @Fred's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that the followig might be of interest:

Let $a>2$. Then there is $b>1$ such that $a=b+1$. Then we get, by the Bernoulli inequality:

$a^n=(b+1)^n \ge 1+nb > 1+n$.

Hence $n(a^{n}-1) > n^2 \ge1$ and we derive

$n(a^{n}-1)-1>0.$

Comment: That was really nice use of the Bernoulli inequality. Thank you @Fred.